# How to keep x axis as continuous date hierarchy without YEAR in PowerBI?

Tags: powerbi

I have a standard date hierarchy and I am trying to create a stacked line chart with daily sales year over year.  I want to display my measure with YEAR in the legend.  So my x-axis should just show Jan1 - Dec31 with no year distinction.  I can do this, however the visual then treats the data as categorical and adds a slider to the x-axis.  My work around for this is to add a column to my calendar table which converts any date to the same date in the year 3000.  I can then use this date as my x-axis and then use the YEAR column from my calendar table as the legend.  It works, but I was hoping there was a better way to keep the Month-Day x-axis as continuous and avoid the slider without having to create a new date column.

Thank you in advance.